# Hard disk Partitions

Tags: macos

I have a two partitions on the Hard disk; *Mavericks* and *Data*.

Anyone know how to stored all the desktop files automatically move to Data partitions.
My ideas is there is no files stored on the first partitions.
//Thanks.

Comment: You can move entire `Home` dir to another partition. Here's nice tutorial: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relocate-your-home-folder-to-another-drive-or-volume--mac-48822

Comment: Just checking - You want any file located on your desktop to be actually stored on your *Data* partition instead of the *~/Desktop* folder on the *Mavericks* drive?

Answer (score 1):

1. Move your desktop to the Data partition.
2. Symlink your ~/Desktop to this new desktop folder.

   ```
   ln -s /Volumes/Data/Desktop ~/Desktop
   ```